# Liquibase refuses to create a database that doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I'm trying to run

```
liquibase update
```

on a database that doesn't exist yet. I would expect it to create the database for me (I'm running with root, so it shouldn't be a problem), but instead I'm getting:

```
/vagrant/liquibase$ ./liquibase update
Liquibase Home is not set.
Liquibase Home: /vagrant/liquibase
Liquibase update Failed: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'test_project'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Connection url parameters to the rescue again!

```
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/dev_project?allowMultiQueries=true&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

the `createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` part did the trick

Comment: what is the source of the url?