# Create database from liquibase maven plugin

Tags: maven, liquibase

I'm able to run liquibase fine against an existing database but I'm trying to also automate the creation of the database.

I'm using the maven plugin with the config below:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And my liquibase.properties file has the following:

```
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
username=postgres
password=mypass
changeLogFile=db.changelog.xml
referenceUsername=postgres
referencePassword=${database.password}
```

According to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322876/liquibase-refuses-to-create-a-database-that-doesnt-exist) on SO adding the URL parameter createDatabaseIfNotExist=true should create the db when the plugin update goal is run.  However, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.0:update (default-cli) on project accommodation: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "mydb" does not exist -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: That URL parameter is specific to MySQL, so it won't work on Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Liquibase will not create the database if it does not exist. Liquibase uses a JDBC driver to communicate with the database, and JDBC doesn't have an API for creating a database from scratch. Many databases don't allow you to create a database using just SQL either, so I think that is why the feature isn't there.

Postgres does have a SQL command that creates a database, so you could try using a `<sql>` change tag that was specific to postgres - something like this:

```
<changeset id="createdatabase" author="steve" dbms="postgres">
  <sql>CREATE DATABASE sales OWNER salesapp TABLESPACE salesspace</sql>
</changeset>
```

This is not tested at all, and may not work.